# Return no-result keywords in select query in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I am currently using the following select query to search in my `Postgres` database

```
select * from res_country where code like any (array['%A%', '%BF%', '%CD%']);
```

It will return a list of record matched with the keyword in the array. However, there will some keywords `which returns no result`. I want to list out these keywords.

Example:
I have the following codes (column code) in my database:

```
AAA
AA
ABF
CCC
BBC
```

and I have an search array as follow:

`array['%A%', '%BF%', '%CD%', '%DA%']`

As we can see

```
%A% matches AAA, AA, ABF
%BF% matches ABF
%CD% matches no code
%DA% matches no code
```

I want to list out keywords like `%CD%, %DA%`

Comment: Can you share some sample data and the result you're trying to achieve? I'm not sure I'm following.

Comment: At a guess, you're going to want to transform this into a left outer join on the keyword list.

Comment: I have just updated the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/afebe/1)

```
select pattern
from
    res_country
    right join
    unnest(array['%A%', '%BF%', '%CD%', '%DA%']) p(pattern) on code like pattern
where code is null
;
```